# ¿Como hacer que mi carpeta del proyecto solo acepte 3 archivos maximo - Laravel?

Tags: laravel, archivo, validación

estoy haciendo un alojamiento de fotos con laravel, y a cada usuario registrado le creo una carpeta con su nombre de usuario y dentro las imágenes que ese usuario suba, el asunto es que siempre al cambiar la foto de perfil el usuario, se almcenan muchas fotos en la carpeta y quiero evitar eso, quiero que en esa carpeta solo se almacene 3 archivos maximo...

este es mi controlador de subir foto...

```
public function changePf(Request $request, $id)
{
    $name_pic = $request->file('pic_pf')->getClientOriginalName();

    $user_name = Auth::user()->name;
    $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('files/'.$user_name.'/img_profile' , $request->file('pic_pf'));

    $table = new User();
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->pic_profile = $path;

    $save = $user->save();

    if ($save)
    {
        return redirect('/profile')->with('msg', 'Foto de perfil actualizada correctamente.!');
    }
    else
    {
        return "Hubo un problema al guardar la foto de perfil";
    }
}
```

¿Que me recomiendan?, gracias de antemano...

Comment: Puede intentar llevar un registro en una tabla, y cuando el usuario suba una fotografìa nueva, que verifique en la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

borrala, solo asegurate que sea la ruta correcta. si es distinta, por lo del enlace que pudiera estar en storage en vez de public, puedes hacer algo como esto.

```
if(!empty($user->pic_profile)){
  $image = str_replace('storage/', 'public/', $user->pic_profile);
  Storage::delete($image);
}
```